# Bash : write in CSV file multiline in one cell for only one column

Tags: arrays, bash, arraylist, export-to-csv, arrayofarrays

I need to complete a csv file with Artifactory files informations, but I have some issue on the format when I'm trying to generate it.

Format waited in the csv :
[image]

Format generated with bad format :
[image]

For that I get on Artifactory for each component the file list in a folder and I get all checksum for each one :

```
function getArtifactoryMavenInfo {
    completPath="$1$commandeAsk"
    
    # get all files in one Artifactory folder => this is OK
    list_MAVEN_files=($(curl -H "Content-Type: text/plain" -u XXX:XXX -X GET "$completPath" | jq ".files" | sed -n -e '/^.*\"uri\"\: \"/p' | sed 's/^.*\"uri\"\: \"\///' | sed 's/".*$//'))

    # all_checksum will have all files with there checksums
    all_checksum=""
    for (( f=0; f<${#list_MAVEN_files[@]}; f++ )); do
        filePath="$1/${list_MAVEN_files[f]}"
        # all checksums have the good format => this is ok
        checksums_MAVEN_sha1=($(curl "$filePath" | jq ".checksums.sha1" | sed 's/"//' | sed 's/"$//'))
        checksums_MAVEN_md5=($(curl "$filePath" | jq ".checksums.md5" | sed 's/"//' | sed 's/"$//'))
        checksums_MAVEN_sha256=($(curl "$filePath" | jq ".checksums.sha256" | sed 's/"//' | sed 's/"$//'))
        # Trying to create an array with all files and there checksums => this is not sure ...
        all_checksum+=$(echo "${list_MAVEN_files[f]} : sha1=${checksums_MAVEN_sha1} / md5=${checksums_MAVEN_md5} / sha256=${checksums_MAVEN_sha256}")
    done
    
    # put the previous array on a list => it will be the third column in the csv
    finalListArtifactorySHA+=($(echo "$all_checksum"))
    # put the path of the folder on a list => it will be for example the first column
    finalListArtifactoryPath+=($(echo "$1/"))
}
```

With that I have all informations I need. Then I try to put all of that in a csv file :

```
echo "Component name;Component version;Artifacts checksums;Artifactory path;Repo path" > $CSV_FILE_NAME
for (( i=0; i<${#finalListComponentName[@]}; i++ )); do
    echo "${finalListComponentName[i]};${finalListComponentVersion[i]};${finalListArtifactorySHA[i]};${finalListArtifactoryPath[i]};${finalListRepoPath[i]}" >> $CSV_FILE_NAME
done
```

Can you please help me? I tried a lot of modifications and checked all forums, but I've never get the result I need on my csv output.

Thank you very much for your help !!!

Comment: Please provide an [mcve] for this.  We have no way to test anything.  Educated guess, you have carriage returns in one (or more) of the values in the arrays, so instead of staying on one line, each information is pushed down to the next line.  Debug CSV in a raw text editor, this way you will ensure that no interpretation of your file is done in Excel (or other that splits CSV file).  Other debug trick, print the content of your arrays, make sure this is ok before moving on.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I give you my full script, I just change paths to artifactory and git. The registry-name parameter is the git super-repo :

```
#!/bin/bash

### launch command : ./Get_Component_Versions_Release.sh registry-name branch ###

printf "\n====> Get_Component_Versions_Release - BEGIN OF SCRIPT <====\n"

### GLOBAL
# | Component name | Repo Path | Component Version | Path artifact Artifactory (URI) | SHA 256 of each file (checksums) |  Path artifact Harbor | SHA 256 of each file
declare -a finalListComponentName=()
declare -a finalListRepoPath=()
declare -a finalListComponentVersion=()
declare -a finalListArtifactoryPath=()
declare -a finalListArtifactorySHA=()

### FUNCTIONS

function getArtifactoryNPMInfo {
    printf "\n====> Get_Component_Versions_Release - getArtifactoryNPMInfo - Begin function <====\n"
    declare -a all_checksum=()
    completPath="$1"
    componentName="$2"
    printf "Full path to packages : $completPath \n"
    
    printf "\n====> Get_Component_Versions_Release - getArtifactoryNPMInfo - Get all checksums <====\n"
    checksums_NPM_sha1=($(curl "$completPath" | jq ".checksums.sha1" | sed 's/"//' | sed 's/"$//'))
    checksums_NPM_md5=($(curl "$completPath" | jq ".checksums.md5" | sed 's/"//' | sed 's/"$//'))
    checksums_NPM_sha256=($(curl "$completPath" | jq ".checksums.sha256" | sed 's/"//' | sed 's/"$//'))
    all_checksum=$(echo "${componentName}:sha1=${checksums_NPM_sha1}/md5=${checksums_NPM_md5}/sha256=${checksums_NPM_sha256}")
    # all_checksum=($(echo "${componentName}"))
    # all_checksum+=($(echo "sha1=${checksums_NPM_sha1}"))
    # all_checksum+=($(echo "md5=${checksums_NPM_md5}"))
    # all_checksum+=($(echo "sha256=${checksums_NPM_sha256}"))
    
    printf "\n====> Get_Component_Versions_Release - getArtifactoryNPMInfo - Get all uri <====\n"
    uri_NPM=($(curl "$completPath" | jq ".uri" | sed 's/"//' | sed 's/"$//'))

    printf "\n====> Get_Component_Versions_Release - getArtifactoryNPMInfo - Push values to list <====\n"
    #finalListArtifactorySHA+=($(echo "${all_checksum}"))
    finalListArtifactorySHA+=($(echo "N/A"))
    finalListArtifactoryPath+=($(echo "$uri_NPM"))
}

function getArtifactoryMavenInfo {
    printf "\n====> Get_Component_Versions_Release - getArtifactoryMavenInfo - Begin function <====\n"
    commandeAsk="?list&deep=1&listFolders=1&mdTimestamps=1"
    completPath="$1$commandeAsk"
    
    printf "Full path to packages : $completPath \n"
    
    printf "\n====> Get_Component_Versions_Release - getArtifactoryMavenInfo - Generate List of files <====\n"
    list_MAVEN_files=($(curl -H "Content-Type: text/plain" -u 502779997:AKCp8hzCzoGCHhwzPst2vHz4gs8vfZRphEqtsoz87pwwHWEWdwD1Yp1qZG3eBF7WJVH9mQD4H -X GET "$completPath" | jq ".files" | sed -n -e '/^.*\"uri\"\: \"/p' | sed 's/^.*\"uri\"\: \"\///' | sed 's/".*$//'))

    all_checksum=""
    for (( f=0; f<${#list_MAVEN_files[@]}; f++ )); do
        filePath="$1/${list_MAVEN_files[f]}"
        printf "filePath = $filePath \n"
        checksums_MAVEN_sha1=($(curl "$filePath" | jq ".checksums.sha1" | sed 's/"//' | sed 's/"$//'))
        checksums_MAVEN_md5=($(curl "$filePath" | jq ".checksums.md5" | sed 's/"//' | sed 's/"$//'))
        checksums_MAVEN_sha256=($(curl "$filePath" | jq ".checksums.sha256" | sed 's/"//' | sed 's/"$//'))
        all_checksum="$all_checksum$(echo "${list_MAVEN_files[f]}:sha1=${checksums_MAVEN_sha1}/md5=${checksums_MAVEN_md5}/sha256=${checksums_MAVEN_sha256}")"
        # all_checksum+=($(echo "${list_MAVEN_files[f]}"))
        # all_checksum+=($(echo "sha1 = ${checksums_MAVEN_sha1}"))
        # all_checksum+=($(echo "md5 = ${checksums_MAVEN_md5}"))
        # all_checksum+=($(echo "sha256 = ${checksums_MAVEN_sha256}"))
    done
    
    printf "\n====> Get_Component_Versions_Release - getArtifactoryMavenInfo - Push values to list <====\n"
    finalListArtifactorySHA+=($(echo "$all_checksum"))
    #finalListArtifactorySHA+=($(echo "N/A"))
    finalListArtifactoryPath+=($(echo "$1/"))
}

function getArtifactoryHelmInfo {
    printf "\n====> Get_Component_Versions_Release - getArtifactoryHelmInfo - Begin function <====\n"
    completPath="$1"
    printf "Full path to packages : $completPath \n"
    
    printf "\n====> Get_Component_Versions_Release - getArtifactoryHelmInfo - Generate List of files <====\n"
    #curl "$completPath"
    
    printf "\n====> Get_Component_Versions_Release - getArtifactoryHelmInfo - Push values to list <====\n"
    finalListArtifactorySHA+=($(echo "N/A"))
    finalListArtifactoryPath+=($(echo "N/A"))
}

### PARAMETERS

printf "\n====> Get_Component_Versions_Release - Get parameters <====\n"
SDKR_TO_USE=$1
BRANCH_TO_USE=$2

printf "\n====> Get_Component_Versions_Release - Print parameters <====\n"
printf "SDKRegistry to use : $SDKR_TO_USE \n"
printf "Branch to update : $BRANCH_TO_USE \n"

printf "\n====> Get_Component_Versions_Release - Check parameters <====\n"
if [ "$#" -eq 2 ]; then
    printf "Number of Parameters OK "
else
    printf "ERROR : Please give all parameters needed : ./Get_Component_Versions_Release.sh registry-name branch"
    exit 1
fi

printf "\n====> Get_REPO - Put Marvin infos <====\n"
git config --global user.email "502779997@ge.com"
git config --global user.name "502779997"

### CODE EXECUTION

printf "\n====> Get_Component_Versions_Release - step 1 - Check SDKRegistry exist <====\n"
if [ -d "$SDKR_TO_USE" ]; then
    printf "Directory $SDKR_TO_USE exists.\n"
    cd $SDKR_TO_USE/
else
    printf "ERROR : No SDKRegistry to use, please launch Get_REPO.sh to get one \n"
    exit 1
fi

printf "\n====> Get_Component_Versions_Release - step 2 - Change branches on SDKR and submodules <====\n"
#git checkout $BRANCH_TO_USE
#git submodule foreach "git checkout '$BRANCH_TO_USE'"

printf "\n====> Get_Component_Versions_Release - step 3 - Declaration of all paths <====\n"
ARTIFACTORY_PATH="https://XXX/artifactory/api/storage"
ARTIFACTORY_MAVEN_PATH="XXX"
ARTIFACTORY_NPM_PATH="XXX"
GIT_PATH="XXX"
SDKR_PATH=$(pwd)

printf "\n====> Get_Component_Versions_Release - step 4 - Get listes <====\n"
cmdGetULRList=($(grep url .gitmodules | sed "s/.*= //"))
#printf "cmdGetULRList : $cmdGetULRList \n"
listComponentName=($(grep url .gitmodules | sed -e "s|.*/||" -e "s/.git//"))
#printf "listComponentName : $listComponentName \n"
listComponentURL=($(grep url .gitmodules | sed "s/.*://"))
#printf "listComponentURL : $listComponentURL \n"
cmdGetPATHonSDKRList=($(grep path .gitmodules | sed "s/.*= //"))
#printf "cmdGetPATHonSDKRList : $cmdGetPATHonSDKRList \n"

printf "\n====> Get_Component_Versions_Release - step 5 - Complete lites <====\n"
currentPos=0
for (( i=0; i<${#cmdGetPATHonSDKRList[@]}; i++ )); do
    printf "\n====> Go to submodule <====\n"
    cd ${cmdGetPATHonSDKRList[i]}
    
    printf "\n====> Path of submodule <====\n"
    pwd
    name="N/A"
    version="N/A"
    
    printf "\n====> Generate list of config files <====\n"
    listPOM=($(find -iname "pom.xml"))
    listJSON=($(find -iname "package.json"))
    listCHART=($(find -iname "chart.yaml"))
    
    printf "\n====> pom.xml case <====\n"
    if [ -z "$listPOM" ]; then
        printf "\n listPOM is empty \n"
    else
        for (( pom=0; pom<${#listPOM[@]}; pom++ )); do
            printf "\n====> generate finalListComponentName <====\n"
            #name=$(cat ${listPOM[pom]} | grep "<artifactId>.*</artifactId>" | head -1 |awk -F'[><]' '{print $3}')
            name=$(xmllint --xpath "//*[local-name()='project']/*[local-name()='artifactId']/text()" ${listPOM[pom]})
            finalListComponentName+=($(echo "$name"))
            
            printf "\n====> generate finalListRepoPath <====\n"
            finalListRepoPath+=($(echo "$GIT_PATH${listComponentURL[i]}"))
            
            printf "\n====> generate finalListComponentVersion <====\n"
            #version=$(cat ${listPOM[pom]} | grep "<version>.*</version>" | head -1 |awk -F'[><]' '{print $3}')
            name=$(xmllint --xpath "//*[local-name()='project']/*[local-name()='version']/text()" ${listPOM[pom]})
            finalListComponentVersion+=($(echo "$version"))
            
            printf "\n====> generate finalListArtifactoryPath and generate finalListArtifactorySHA <====\n"
            fullPath="$ARTIFACTORY_PATH/$ARTIFACTORY_MAVEN_PATH/$name/$version"
            getArtifactoryMavenInfo $fullPath
            
            # printf "New line : Name => ${finalListComponentName[currentPos]} Path => ${finalListRepoPath[currentPos]} Version => ${finalListComponentVersion[currentPos]} \n"
            
            currentPos=$((currentPos + 1))
        done
    fi
    
    printf "\n====> package.json case <====\n"
    if [ -z "$listJSON" ]; then
        printf "\n listJSON is empty \n"
    else
        for (( json=0; json<${#listJSON[@]}; json++ )); do
            printf "\n====> generate finalListComponentName <====\n"
            name=$(cat ${listJSON[json]} | grep name | head -1 | awk -F: '{ print $2 }' | sed 's/[",]//g' | tr -d '[[:space:]]' | sed 's/.*\///g')
            finalListComponentName+=($(echo "$name"))
            
            printf "\n====> generate finalListRepoPath <====\n"
            finalListRepoPath+=($(echo "$GIT_PATH${listComponentURL[i]}"))
            
            printf "\n====> generate finalListComponentVersion <====\n"
            version=$(cat ${listJSON[json]}| grep version | head -1 | awk -F: '{ print $2 }' | sed 's/[",]//g' | tr -d '[[:space:]]')
            finalListComponentVersion+=($(echo "$version"))
            
            printf "\n====> generate finalListArtifactoryPath and finalListArtifactorySHA <====\n"
            fullPath="$ARTIFACTORY_PATH/$ARTIFACTORY_NPM_PATH/$name/-/@ifabric/$name-$version.tgz"
            fileName="$name-$version.tgz"
            getArtifactoryNPMInfo $fullPath $fileName

            # printf "New line : Name => ${finalListComponentName[currentPos]} Path => ${finalListRepoPath[currentPos]} Version => ${finalListComponentVersion[currentPos]} \n"
            
            currentPos=$((currentPos + 1))
        done
    fi
    
    printf "\n====> chart.yaml case <====\n"
    if [ -z "$listCHART" ]; then
        printf "\n listCHART is empty \n"
    else
        for (( chart=0; chart<${#listCHART[@]}; chart++ )); do
            printf "\n====> generate finalListComponentName <====\n"
            name=$(cat ${listCHART[chart]} | grep name | head -1 | awk -F: '{ print $2 }' | tr -d '[[:space:]]')
            finalListComponentName+=($(echo "$name"))
            
            printf "\n====> generate finalListRepoPath <====\n"
            finalListRepoPath+=($(echo "$GIT_PATH${listComponentURL[i]}"))
            
            printf "\n====> generate finalListComponentVersion <====\n"
            version=$(cat ${listCHART[chart]}| grep version | head -1 | awk -F: '{ print $2 }' | tr -d '[[:space:]]')
            finalListComponentVersion+=($(echo "$version"))
            
            printf "\n====> generate finalListArtifactoryPath and finalListArtifactorySHA <====\n"
            finalListArtifactorySHA+=($(echo "N/A"))
            finalListArtifactoryPath+=($(echo "N/A"))

            # printf "New line : Name => ${finalListComponentName[currentPos]} Path => ${finalListRepoPath[currentPos]} Version => ${finalListComponentVersion[currentPos]} \n"
            
            currentPos=$((currentPos + 1))
        done
    fi
    printf "Go back to SDKR root \n"
    cd $SDKR_PATH
done

printf "\n====> Get_Component_Versions_Release - step 6 - Create CSV file <====\n"

CSV_FILE_NAME="componentFullDocumentation_$BRANCH_TO_USE.csv"
cd ..
echo "Component name;Component version;Artifacts checksums;Artifactory path;Repo path" > $CSV_FILE_NAME
for (( i=0; i<${#finalListComponentName[@]}; i++ )); do
    echo "${finalListComponentName[i]};${finalListComponentVersion[i]};${finalListArtifactorySHA[i]};${finalListArtifactoryPath[i]};${finalListRepoPath[i]}" >> $CSV_FILE_NAME
done

printf "\n====> Get_Component_Versions_Release - END OF SCRIPT <====\n"
```